# Using JSON objects create a div for every object that's getting populated in JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have one big div where it should show the list of JSON objects. Each object should be different DIV element with few details of each object, similarly one behind another.

I have a comments in a page, where it's details are stored in JSON object as {author,id,comments,time}, so wanted to get list of all comments in a particular page into one DIV. Each comment should be a child Div's (showing author name, comment and time commented)for a Parent DIV

Comment: What have you tried? What do you have? Give us something. And do something.

Comment: Write a loop that adds a child DIV for each element in the array of JSON objects.

Comment: Since you've given us such an ambiguous question, here's an ambiguous answer: You should definitely do _something_

Comment: I have a comments in a page, where it's details are stored in Json object as {author,id,comments,time}, so wanted to get list off all comments in a particular page at one place. Each comment should be shown as a single div showing author name, comment and time commented.

Answer (score 0):

**Html Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="app1.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

</head>

<body> 
  <div id="placeholder1"></div>
  <div id="placeholder2"></div>
  <script>
    var data={
      "firstName":"Ray",
      "lastName":"Villalobos",
      "joined":2012
    };

    var data1={
      "firstName":"John",
      "lastName":"Doe",
      "joined":2013
    };
    document.getElementById("placeholder1").innerHTML=data.firstName+" "+data.lastName+" "+data.joined;
    document.getElementById("placeholder2").innerHTML=data1.firstName+" "+data1.lastName+" "+data1.joined;
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hope it helps somewhat

Answer (score 0):

The problem is finding a DIV big enough to hold the data. Most are just average size DIVs and those won't work for this kind of application. ;)

The code snippet below downloads Yahoo weather data, converts the key-value pairs to text, and displays them each in a DIV within the BIG DIV.

update:
Modified slightly for OP's new requirements.

**Run the code snippet to see it in action:**

```html
<html>
<body>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
<style type="text/css">
 div {padding: 4px;border: 1px red dotted;font-family: monospace;font-size: 10px;}
    h2 {font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive; font-size:24px; color:steelblue;}
</style>
<h2>A REALLY SUPER BIG DIV WITH DATA</h2>
<div id="BIG_DIV"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function callback(data) {
 document.getElementById('BIG_DIV').innerHTML = getKeys( data );
}

function getKeys( obj ) {
 var key, html='';
 for( key in obj) {
  if (typeof obj[key] == 'object') html += '<div>' + getKeys( obj[key] ) + '</div>';
   else html += '<div>' + key + ':' + obj[key] + '</div>';
 } 
 return html;
}

</script>
<!-- Yahoo Weather data -->
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="Paris")&format=json&callback=callback'></script>
</body>
</html>
```